# get SYN timestamp using lbcurl

Tags: c, tcp, libcurl, traffic

using libcurl, I can perform file download.
Using libcurl, I can get some utile information like BytesReceived, download status ...
Is it possible to get SYN (TCP level) timestamps using libcurl?